# Post data to another site from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a web form which is posting a few fields to a payment site. The structure the example is using is

```
<form method="post" action="<%= FormAction %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Hash" value="<%= sHash %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MID" value="<%= sMID %>" />
    ......
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Post Data" />
</div>
```

Within the example project they have set the same variables within the code behind file (after declaring them) with values. When the button above is clicked it posts the data to the relevant page without errors and the user is redirected to the payment page.

So i am now trying the same under the click event of an image button on my site but doesnt work:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonCheckout" runat="server" Text="Go to payment page" ImageUrl="~/Images/Payment.gif" />
```

and of course it doesnt work, ive added all the markup as above and added all sample code.

When i run the app it flashes and stops. I look in Fiddler and notice its not going to the payment site at all. The masterpage has   declared in it - incase this makes any difference.

Reading around it seems i could use the image button to post the data and do exactly the same as the submit button (submit button is above which was part of the sample application from the payment provider) by using the onClick event in the markup with Javascript but im struggling to understand how to tie it all together and lost to what i could do next to get this working?

Comment: It would have been helpful if someone would have directed me to a page with an example or gave me an example so i could get a better understanding rather than down voting my post after i have explained where i was confused!!

Comment: I agree and find that there seem to be some who will do this with absolutely no explanation.  Anyway I've +1'd it back up for you.

Comment: Can you drop the code behind in your post please?

Comment: Thanks for that Westie (and Tim for providing possibly an answer). I took a different approach as i sensed i was going to waste time trying to figure it out myself after i got down voted by 1 and thought others would do the same. All i did was added the sample code to a new page and it worked. The problem with this was it meant the user had one extra step to take before getting to the check out page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just post form data with an image button. You need to submit the form data - otherwise your image button is just a link. I do this a lot with Javascript.

Try adding `this.form.submit()` to the clientclick. Or name your form and use `this.formname.submit()`

Either of those should post your form data.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can such so write:
    <form id="Form2" method="post" runat="server" action="<%= FormAction %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Hash" value="<%= sHash %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MID" value="<%= sMID %>" />
    ......
    <div class="submit">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonCheckout" runat="server" Text="Go to payment page"/>
    </div>
    </form>

but you must add a few attributes in top of web page,eg:

    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" EnableEventValidation="false" EnableViewStateMac="false" ValidateRequest="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" %>
```

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you are asking me to try? And how this ties to my question?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the OP.